# Matlab full octave and one-third octave analysis

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing

I am trying to implement an octave and 1/3-Octave-Band filters in Matlab. Unfortunately, I do not have access to the Acoustic toolbox but have tried to use the *fdesign.octave* in Matlab, but am not sure if I am going down the right path or not - and would appreciate any help/advice.

The following is my signal (Fs=10,000Hz) taken across 70 seconds:

```
Fs = 10000;            % Sampling frequency
T = 1/Fs;             % Sampling period
L = 700000;             % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;        % Time vector
S = 0.7*sin(2*pi*50*t) + sin(2*pi*120*t);
x = S + 2*randn(size(t));
```

Implementation of one-third octave:

```
d = fdesign.octave(3,'Class 1','N,F0',6,11000,44100);
Hd = design(d);
y= filter(Hd,x);
```

Figure of original and filtered signals:

[image: Original and Filtered Signals]

At this point, I have a question - How would one plot the data produced by *fdesign.octave* in octave or one-third-octave bands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a complete implementation, use [this](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/69-octave) from the Matlab file exchange. No acoustics toolbox required. Included demos should solve your plotting question.